# Multi select option in listbox added dynamically in c#

Tags: asp.net, listbox, dynamic-controls

I am adding a listbox dynamically inside a panel. I need to select multiple items in the listbox. This is a filter requirement for filter criteria IN. For ex it should look like below:

```
Label  Filter ListBox_items
----------------------------------
Fruits   IN      Mango
                 Apple
                 Grapes
```

Below is the code

```
     ListBox dynListBox = new ListBox();
     dynListBox.ID = "DControl1" + i.ToString();
     dynListBox.Style["Position"] = "relative";
     dynListBox.Attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
     dynListBox.EnableViewState = true;        
     dynListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
     Panel2.Controls.Add(dynListBox);
```

I am not able to select multiple items. Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows Forms, you can test like this:

```
dynListBox.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
```

The best way to find out how to implement dynamic controls is to create one static on your form with the desired behaviour, and then check the code generated in your form.designer.cs

Comment: its asp.net web application